# How to separate layouts between secured and non secured pages

Tags: angular

Trying to figure out how to separate layouts between public and secured.

I read there is a concept around children when setting up routes but cannot find a example where this is enacted.

Essentially what i want to achieve:

Public (non-secured)

- -Login
- -Registration
- -Change Password

have layout without md-toolbar and md-sidenav

Secure

- Dashboard
- Profile
- AddItem

only accessible after login and have a layout with md-toolbar and md-sidenav

If anyone has a working example on plunker or similar would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this with proper use of routing and component configuration.

```
AppComponent - no layout goes here
  children: 
     path: '', PublicRootComponent -  Add your layout for your public component to this guy. 
                                      He has an embedded router-outlet to put the nested content
                                      into the correct position
      children:   <- these children will use public's layout
        path: 'login', LoginComponent    
        path: 'registration', RegistrationComponent

     path: 'secure', SecureRootComponent - add your layout for your secured components
                                         - again, this has a router-layout 
                                           to put nested content in correct position
        children: <- these children will use secure's layout

           path: 'dashboard', DashBoardComponent
           path: 'profile', ProfileComponent
```

Just note that the secured components will be accessed via 'secure/dashboard', and 'secure/profile' in my example.

You can change things around depending on how you want your URLs to work, but the concept remains the same

**EDIT:**

To add some examples,

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
     .....
</head>
<body> 
   <my-app></my-app>    (or whatever your app selector is)
</body>
</html>
```

app-component.html

Notice that the app component doesn't add any layout

**PublicRootComponent**

```
<h1>I am public root</h1>
<div class="public-root-styling">
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

You create your layout for your public pages and put your router-outlet tag whereever you want your nested content to go in that overall layout.

**SecureRootComponent**

```
 <md-sidenav-container>
   <md-toolbar> I am secured content layout</md-toolbar>
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
 </md-sidenav-container>
```

Same applies to the secure root - create your layout within that component itself and use router outlet tag to mark where you want your secured components to be content-injected.

Does that make sense?

Comment: I will give this a test as soon as i get a chance. If it does do the trick will be awesome and you will be my instant friend :). (this has been driving me crazy).

Answer (score 0):

you can use AutoGuard that implement CanActivate.

```
export class  AutoGuard implements CanActivate{
  constructor(private _sessionService : SessionService){}
  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    //Some condition
    return true;
  }
}
```

at your write

```
path: 'some-path',
component: YOUR_SECURE_COMPONENT ,
canActivate : [AutoGuard]
```

Comment: How is that related to multiple layouts setup? how do you tell app to differentiate between layouts?

Comment: you need add other route with the same path and without guard after the secure route.